# Python Pandas ExcelWriter append to sheet creates a new sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I would I really appreciate some help.

I'm trying to use a loop to create sheets, and add data to those sheets for every loop. The position of my data is correct, however Panda `ExcelWriter` creates a new sheet instead of appending to the one created the first time the loop runs.

I'm a beginner, and right function is over form, so forgive me.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd


# initial files for dataframes
excel_file = 'output.xlsx'
setup_file = 'setup.xlsx'

# write to excel
output_filename = 'output_final.xlsx'




df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)  # create dataframe of entire sheet
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')',
                                                                                                       '')  # clean dataframe titles

df_setup = pd.read_excel(setup_file)
df_setup.columns = df_setup.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')',
                                                                                                                   '')  # clean dataframe titles

df_2 = pd.merge(df, df_setup)  # Merge data with setup to have krymp size for each wire in dataframe

df_2['wirelabel'] = "'" + df_2['cable'] + "_" + df_2['function_code'] + "-" + df_2['terminal_strip'] + ":" + df_2[
    'terminal']  # creates column for the wirelabel by appending columns with set delimiters. #TODO: delimiters to be by inputs.

df_2.sort_values(by=['switchboard'])  # sort so we get proper order

switchboard_unique = df.switchboard.unique().tolist()  # crate variable containing unique switchboards for printing to excel sheets


def createsheets(output_filename, sheetname, row_start, column_start, df_towrite):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
        df_towrite.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, columns=['wirelabel'], startrow=row_start, startcol=column_start, index=False, header=False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()

def sorter():
    for s in switchboard_unique:
        df_3 = df_2.loc[df_2['switchboard'] == s]
        krymp_unique = df_3.krymp.unique().tolist()
        krymp_unique.sort()
        # print(krymp_unique)
        column_start = 0
        row_start = 0
        for k in krymp_unique:
            df_3.loc[df_3['krymp'] == k]
            # print(k)
            # print(s)
            # print(df_3['wirelabel'])
            createsheets(output_filename, s, row_start, column_start, df_3)
            column_start = column_start + 1

sorter()
```

**current behavior:**

if sheetname is = sheet, then my script creates sheet1, sheet2, sheet3..etc.

[pictureofcurrent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onbiS.png)

**Wanted behavior**

Create a sheet for each item in "df_3", and put data into columns according to the position calculated in column_start. The position in my code works, just goes to the wrong sheet.

[pictureofwanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwp4f.png)

I hope it's clear what im trying to accomplish, and all help is appriciated.
I tried all example codes i have sound regarding writing to excel.

Comment: Can you please make a minimal working example of your code? As in, try to reduce your code to the ONE thing that does not work as you want it to. Your code is too complicated with too much going on to really nail down where something goes wrong. (Plus this is a standard technique for debugging your own code - try to find the error source by reducing the problem.)

Comment: I agree with PoorYorick. Apart from that: you're iterating here `for s in switchboard_unique:` and thus passing a *new* `s` to `createsheets()` every iteration through the loop. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: I will try to simplify my code later. Can you perhaps clairyfy if the append functionality in pandas actually can spend to sheets, more than once, or just apend to the workbook? I might have misunderstood the functionality of append perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

I know my code is not a work of art, but I will update this post with the answer to my own question for the sake of completeness, and if anyone stumbles on this post.

It turns out i misunderstood the capabilities of the "append" function in Pandas "pd.ExcelWriter". It is not possible to append to a sheet already existing, the sheet will get overwritten though mode is set to 'a'.

Realizing this i changed my code to build a dataframe for the entire sheet (df_sheet), an then call the "createsheets" function in my code. The first version wrote my data column by column.

"Final" code:

```
import pandas as pd

# initial files for dataframes
excel_file = 'output.xlsx'
setup_file = 'setup.xlsx'

# write to excel
output_filename = 'output_final.xlsx'
column_name = 0

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)  # create dataframe of entire sheet
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')',
                                                                                                       '')  # clean dataframe titles

df_setup = pd.read_excel(setup_file)
df_setup.columns = df_setup.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')',
                                                                                                                   '')  # clean dataframe titles

df_2 = pd.merge(df, df_setup)  # Merge data with setup to have krymp size for each wire in dataframe

df_2['wirelabel'] = "'" + df_2['cable'] + "_" + df_2['function_code'] + "-" + df_2['terminal_strip'] + ":" + df_2[
    'terminal']  # creates column for the wirelabel by appending columns with set delimiters. #TODO: delimiters to be by inputs.

df_2.sort_values(by=['switchboard'])  # sort so we get proper order

switchboard_unique = df.switchboard.unique().tolist()  # crate variable containing unique switchboards for printing to excel sheets




def createsheets(output_filename, sheetname, df_towrite):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
        df_towrite.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=False, header=True)


def to_csv_file(output_filename, df_towrite):
    df_towrite.to_csv(output_filename, mode='w', index=False)

def sorter():
    for s in switchboard_unique:
        df_3 = df_2.loc[df_2['switchboard'] == s]

        krymp_unique = df_3.krymp.unique().tolist()
        krymp_unique.sort()

        column_start = 0
        row_start = 0
        df_sheet = pd.DataFrame([])

        for k in krymp_unique:
            df_5 = df_3.loc[df_3['krymp'] == k]
            df_4 = df_5.filter(['wirelabel'])


            column_name = "krymp " + str(k) + " Tavle: " + str(s)

            df_4 = df_4.rename(columns={"wirelabel": column_name})
            df_4 = df_4.reset_index(drop=True)
            df_sheet = pd.concat([df_sheet, df_4], axis=1)

            column_start = column_start + 1
            row_start = row_start + len(df_5.index) + 1

        createsheets(output_filename, s, df_sheet)
        to_csv_file(s + ".csv", df_sheet)


sorter()
```

Thank you.